# Check Jwt token Expiry react drf

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Sorry if i asking at wrong place. I am using Django drf for api and serving front from react in my app. i am using simplejwt for authentication and i want to check expiry of access and refresh token from react to generate access token when expire . what will be better way any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) reference

2 JWT token are generated `access` and `refresh`

`refresh` is long living and `access` is for short living.

if your `access` expires use `refresh` token to get access token

Sample

```
 curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"refresh":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3BrIjoxLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImNvbGRfc3R1ZmYiOiLimIMiLCJleHAiOjIzNDU2NywianRpIjoiZGUxMmY0ZTY3MDY4NDI3ODg5ZjE1YWMyNzcwZGEwNTEifQ.aEoAYkSJjoWH1boshQAaTkf8G3yn0kapko6HFRt7Rh4"}' \
  http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/
```

Response:

```
{"access":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3BrIjoxLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiY29sZF9zdHVmZiI6IuKYgyIsImV4cCI6MTIzNTY3LCJqdGkiOiJjNzE4ZTVkNjgzZWQ0NTQyYTU0NWJkM2VmMGI0ZGQ0ZSJ9.ekxRxgb9OKmHkfy-zs1Ro_xs1eMLXiR17dIDBVxeT-w"}
```

You can configure validity period of both token in configuration

```
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
```

Still if you want to generate manually

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

`get_tokens_for_user` will return the serialized representations of new refresh and access tokens

Comment: but how can i send access token to react when expire

Comment: in existing flow how are you sending token to react ?